# How to work with Vue.js and Semantic UI?

Tags: vue.js, cdn, semantic-ui

I love Vue.js and would like to incorporate that into Semantic UI. I'm very new to all of this so this may not come out correctly. I've looked in many places to see how to put the two together, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676215/using-vue-js-with-semantic-ui), and it gets very overwhelming.

Then I thought why can't I just install Semantic UI and link to the vuejs CDN so I can use that. Is that a legitimate way to integrate the two? Could I also do the reverse and install vue-cli and link to the Semantic CDN?

I feel like I'm missing something here but using these two inside of webpack and making sure dependencies are setup and working properly is way too big for me.

I like the idea of [Vuetify.js](https://vuetifyjs.com/) and [Element](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US), but I don't like the possibility of these integrations going to the wayside soon and being "stuck" with it and having to learn something else in the near future.

Comment: I use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-ui-vue2

Comment: @DmitryShmakov Put this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

At the end of the day these are just javascript and css files. Include them into your html and start coding. These complicated build processes you mentioned are suited for large applications that require the overhead of webpack.

I've never used Semantic but it looks to be just a widget library, while Vue is a view framework. There is no special set up required to get these 2 to work with each other, just start adding Semantic elements into your Vue templates.